# кириллический домен laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, роутинг

Подскажите с проблемой - есть сайт с кириллическим доменом, как мне сделать , чтобы ларавель стал его понимать? плюс есть и поддомен.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'кириллица.рф'], function() {

Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.кириллица.рф'], function()
```

{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное надо перекодировать в punycode

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'xn--80apaahia1b8c.xn--p1ai'], function() {
```

Comment: Вы сделали мой день! Пуникод , это что-то )))))